# Not getting the column access in Ignite Cache created and loaded from Oracle

Tags: ignite, gridgain, in-memory-data-grid

I am doing a POC to ingest data from Oracle to Ignite cluster and Fetch the 
data from Ignite in another application. When I created the Model and Cache, 
I specified the Key as String and value as Custom Object. Data loaded to 
cluster but then I querying "SELECT * FROM TB_USER" I am getting only two 
column, i.e. _KEY and _VAL. I am trying to get all the column from the 
TB_USER. What are the configuration required for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways of configuring SQL tables in Ignite:

1. DDL statements ([create table](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table)). As far as I can see, you used something else.
2. [QueryEntities](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes#section-queryentity-based-configuration). You should enlist all columns that you want to see in your table in the [QueryEntity#fields](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/QueryEntity.html#setFields-java.util.LinkedHashMap-) property. All names should correspond to field names of your Java objects.
3. [Annotations](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes#annotation-based-configuration). Fields, that are annotated as [@QuerySqlField](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/annotations/QuerySqlField.html) will become columns in your table.

Comment: In the case of *3.* `setIndexedTypes` should also be called (or specified via XML).